# Can I have a scripts call each other? How does packer make it possible to compose many scripts?

Tags: packer

I haven't found any examples of this so I am not sure it's possible.

I want to have utility scripts other packer scripts use. Can scripts call each other directly?

For example if inside of script1.ps1 it calls script2.ps1 (via relative path) will it be there? Will packer upload both files to the same location and the scripts can access each other?

```
{
  "script": "./script1.ps1",
  "type": "powershell"
},
{
  "script": "./script2.ps1",
  "type": "powershell"
}
```

What if I have them in diff folders like this, will I be able to access script2 inside script1 like `./../subdir/script2.ps1`?

```
{
  "script": "./otherdir/script1.ps1",
  "type": "powershell"
},
{
  "script": "./subdir/script2.ps1",
  "type": "powershell"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can certainly do that, although I am not sure what the real advantage is over running the two Powershell provisions like you are already are.

For the first script to call the second, the second script will already have to be present on the target machine. You can do the following:

```
{
    "type": "file",
    "source": "./script2.ps1",
    "destination": "C:/Windows/Temp/script2.ps1"
},
{
    "script": "./script1.ps1",
    "type": "powershell"
}
```

Call *script2* from *script1* and then remove it:

```
& C:\Windows\Temp\script2.ps1
Remove-Item C:\Windows\Temp\script2.ps1
```